# Map two sf objects on one map with mapview

Tags: r, sf, mapview

I have two sf objects, `precincts` and `elemZones`. I want to make a mapview object showing the boundaries of both sf objects, and I want to style each sf object differently. My code so far.

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)

precincts <- read_sf("precincts.shp")
elemZones <- read_sf("elemZones.shp")

mapview(
  x = elemZones,
  legend = F,
  color = "black",
  alpha.regions = 0,
  popup = F
)
```

This only maps `elemZones`. How do I add `precincts`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapview` used to have a function `addFeature()` that is now in `leafem`

```r
m <- mapview(elemZones, ...)
leafem::addFeatures(m, precincts)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to style both of them can do

```r
mapview(elemZones, ...) +
  mapview(precincts, ...)
```

where the `...` here refer to additional styling.

If you only want to style one of them you can simply do

```r
mapview(elemZones) +
  precincts
```